# When using SBT, is there a generic way to hot-fix a Scala dependency?

Tags: scala, sbt

Let's say I am creating an SBT project called `Y` which is using the package `X` in an SBT build:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.something" %% "X" % XVersion
)
```

I've learned that `X` contains a minor bug, which the developer is working on (thank you!). The code of `X` (built with SBT) is available to clone and I know how to hot-fix this issue while the developer works on it.

Here's what I would love to be able to do:

1. Clone `X` to `~/code/X`
2. Create the hot-fix by just editing the code
3. In the `build.sbt` for my own project `Y`, replace `"org.something" %% "X" % XVersion` with a link to `~/code/X` so that my own code is compiled with the hot-fix.

Is there a general way to do this? There's a good chance this is described in the [SBT Docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/index.html), I'd be happy for a pointer - there's a lot of docs with new terminology.

Example in point (but the question is about the general case): This [build file](https://github.com/tpolecat/doobie/blob/main/build.sbt) for a package I'm trying to hot-fix is complex, and I'd love to have a way of hot-fixing without requiring to understand this build file fully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the dependency code and then run `sbt publishLocal` which will create a new local version of the dependency with the changes applied, you can then edit your `build.sbt` to use that new version and that is all you need for a local setup

If you have some CI pipeline or you deeply your code you would need to do more things but this is the basic idea.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I had to adjust the package name to the auto-generated name in Ivy, but am now able to hot-fix.